# Possible vandalism?

Tags: support, bug

Sorry to bother everyone, but I found this particular link over on the physics main page [Could the recent evidence of a gravitational force orbiting the solar system indicate not the existence of a ninth planet, but rather a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/230919/mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm) and I didn't see a question attached to it but three answers to a question which did not appear to be there.

Has this question been vandalized? And if so, can action be taken to restore the original question?

Comment: ok. I swear, a moment ago it was just showing a series of "m"s and now the question is back. WTF is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just look at the [edit history](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/230919/revisions) of the question. The OP doesn't like their question anymore, so they want to get rid of it. However, they cannot delete the question due to the up voted answers. So they are trying to "delete" the question by making poor edits that you saw. Other, responsible users are trying to put the question back to the most relevant version. You were watching this short "edit battle" as it was going on.

Whenever you see activity that is odd like this, the best thing to do is just raise a custom flag for moderators to sort out. In this case a moderator has temporarily locked the question to prevent the OP from making more pointless edits.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I got very confused for a moment there and thought I needed to report it here. Glad that this all worked out ok.

Comment: It never hurts (much) to ask about it here, but in this case flagging is the way to go. Posting on meta doesn't accomplish anything that flagging doesn't accomplish faster, as far as actually putting a stop to the edit war.

Comment: @AaronStevens Why was he embarrased by his question? What actually happened to him? Did he comment anything about why he wants to remove his question?